# Convert random tree to directed tree in netwokx

Tags: graph, tree, networkx

I have generated a random tree using networkx.

```py
A = nx.random_tree(15)
```

I am trying to convert it to a directed graph (i.e. tree).

```py
G = nx.to_directed(A)
```

However, the result is a graph with two directions.

I would like to get the output as one direction tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.to_directed.html#networkx.Graph.to_directed):

> Returns:  G – A directed graph with the same name, same nodes, **and with each edge (u, v, data) replaced by two directed edges (u, v, data) and (v, u, data)**.

If you want to delete reversed edges, you can write something like this:

```
G = nx.random_tree(10)
H = nx.DiGraph([(u,v) for (u,v) in G.edges() if u<v])
```

So `H` will be the tree you needed:

[image]